# Setter method being called before create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a `new` form that creates an `Item` (all the codes are obviously simplified):

```html
<%= simple_form_for @item do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :brand_name %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The current user will create an item and link it to a new or to an existing brand.

This field doesn't exist in the database; it'll be used as a way to associate all models. Hence, I create its getter and setter.

```rb
def Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :brand

  attr_accessible :brand_name

  def brand_name
    brand.try :name
  end

  def brand_name=(name)
    if name.present?
      brand = user.brands.find_or_initialize_by_name(name)
      brand if brand.save
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @item = current_user.items.build
  end

  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(params[:item])

    if @item.save
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when the form is submitted, I get this error, which lies in the `product_name=()` method. I've done some debugging through Rails' console and it goes all fine, but in the browser **the setter method is called before the `create` action**. That is, the record doesn't even have a user associated to it. I tried leaving the `create` method empty, for example, but nothing different happens.

```
undefined method `brands' for nil:NilClass
```

What is really weird is that this was working a couple of weeks ago (I've checked my git commits and the code is identical).

I though about calling the `before_create` callback, but there's no way to know which user should be linked.

**UPDATE**

I'm using Sorcery as the authentication handler. Everything always works fine, except for this create action.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  belongs_to :company
  has_many :items
end
```

```rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :brands, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: you can find out who is calling the setter by adding `p caller` to your setter. It will give you some idea.

Comment: Please add the `User` model source.

Comment: I added the User and the Company models. And took a look at the caller's response, but it didn't really help me.